# Login authentication in node.js using sqlite3 - bookshelf

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, bookshelf.js

I'm trying to create a very simple login authentication in node.js, using bookshelf and sqlite3.

Yes i know there are many many examples on the internet, but none really uses either sqlite or bookshelf, they are all mostly based on passport and mongoose.

When i try to check the login, i get the error data.

**This is my code**

**Login.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var knex = require('knex')(require('../knexfile.js').development);
var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);
var app = express();

var User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
tableName: 'users'
});

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.render('Login');
});

router.post('/', function (req, res) {

var userName = req.body.user_name;
var pw = req.body.password;
var user_name = User.user_name;
var password = User.password;

if (userName == user_name && pw == password)
{
    console.log("Success!");
}
else
{
    console.log("Error!");
}
});
module.exports = router;
```

**Login.ejs**

```
<h2>Login</h2>
<form method="post">
<label>User name</label><br>
<input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name"/><br><br>
<label>Password</label><br>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password"/><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

**Thank you very much!**

I tried displaying values as suggested and i realized both

```
var user_name = User.user_name;
var password = User.password;
```

are undefined, which means there must be something wrong with query or something?

**UPDATE**

[image]

**UPDATE1**

If i try this code...

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
new Users().fetch().then(function (processUsers) {
    console.log(processUsers.toJSON());     
});
});
```

I get displayed user who tried to login...all of his data...hovewever...if i do this:

```
var us_name = processUsers.user_name;
console.log(us_name);
```

it says value is **undefined**

Comment: If you print out the variables `userName`, `user_name`, `pw` and `password` just before the `if`, are they what you expect?

Comment: @Pedro after using console.log, i found out that user_name = User.user_name and password = User.password are "Undefined", which means no values are returned from database...

Comment: Show me console.log of processUsers and processUsers.toJSON() please (blank out the username and password).

Comment: @Pedro i've managed to fix the problem, ill post the solution soon

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with bookshelf but you may want to try something like this:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    new User().fetchAll().then(processUsers).catch(catchErrors);

    function processUsers(users) {
        console.log(users);
        var loggedIn = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            if (users[i].user_name == req.body.user_name && users[i].password == req.body.password) {
                loggedIn = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (loggedIn) {
            console.log("Success!");
        } else {
            console.log("Error!");
        }
    }

    function catchErrors(error) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log('An error occured');
    }
});
```

or

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    new User({user_name : req.body.user_name, password: req.body.password}).fetch().then(processUser).catch(catchErrors);

    function processUser(user) {
        console.log(user);
        console.log("Success!");
    }

    function catchErrors(error) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log('An error occured');
    }
});
```

Bare in mind that you will want to hash and salt passwords stored on the server. If you don't know what that is, please take a look before running this stuff live as it's very important.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. If i use the first option, i get "cannot read property "user_name" of null""....and if i use the second option, everything is a success, even tho if a user doesn't even exist...

Comment: In the first case, what does the `console.log(users)` return?